# Apache2 on RASPBIAN error - AH01916 - Port 80 on standard https (443) error

Tags: raspbian, nextcloud

I am getting following error in the apache2 error.log file:

AH01916: Init: (127.0.1.1:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!

I am running Apache2 on Raspbian. The website has SSL certificate through certbot (by eff.org) using letsencrypt.org. I have configured the *-le-ssl.conf file under sites-enabled/ include:

- SSLEngine on
- ServerAdmin
- ServerName
- ServerAlias
- ServerAlias
- SSLCertificateFile - %File path%
- SSLCertificateKeyFile - %File path%
- Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

Am I missing something? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: This is not a Raspbian specific question, indeed is not a Raspbian question at all. Tags are `raspbian` and `nextcloud`, however missing the `apache`.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](http://apache-http-server.18135.x6.nabble.com/configured-HTTP-80-on-the-standard-HTTPS-443-port-tp5036532p5036533.html), *you are serving regular HTTP traffic on what is usually an HTTPS port. This is because you do not have any SSL configuration on the virtual host on port 443. You need "SSLEngine on" and certificate information at least*.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. I've checked the same post and appended configuration. Hence first line as sslengine on as part of config. But this isn't helping.

Comment: The original poster (OP) in his/her [post](http://apache-http-server.18135.x6.nabble.com/configured-HTTP-80-on-the-standard-HTTPS-443-port-tp5036532p5036539.html) clearly says the suggestion fixed the problem. TBH, I don't use Apache and can certainly't confirm if that will fix the issue. However, in the meantime awaiting for solution(s) from other readers here, it wouldn't be a bad idea to contact the OP in the post to find out more how the suggestion fixed the issue.